# traverse the bit pattern of an array of hexadecimals in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, nasm, x86-16

I am busy with a uni assignment that involves creating a small program with nasm using x86 architecture. I am working on a virtual desktop(windows xp, 32 bit). We are only allowed to use the general purpose registes ax,bx,cx,dx pointer registers si,di.

I know this is not the place to get help for assignments and so I wont ask for a solution to my problem but rather an explanation to understand something.

I need to take a string of hex numbers ie. `num1: db 06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h,06h`
(I am assuming this is correct). Basically this string of hex represent a number that is enlarged. In this case each hex is a bit pattern (for each 0 a space will be printed and for each 1 a $ will be printed), and for each new hex we move the next line and start printing again. I understand this will be done with loops and I will try figure that out on my own. What I can't seem to figure out is this whole concept of a bit pattern.

A simpler example is as follows: lets say `num1: 06h,06h,06h`
**First question**: Am i correct in saying that num1 contains 3 bytes(or is it 6)

For each hex number there is an equivalent bit pattern(00000110 in this case)
I want to move the hex number `06h` into a register and then step through its bit pattern. How on earth do I do that, I stepped through the following code using debug and the bx register had some weird hex values in which means I'm obviously not understanding this,

```
; code 
bits 16
org 0x100
jmp main
num1: db 06h,06h,06h
main:
       mov ax,num1
       mov si,ax     ;points to address
       mov cx,8      ;loop counter
loop_1:      
          mov bx,[si]  ;I assumed this would get the first bit (0) in this case
          ... compare to 0 or 1 and print etc...
          inc si
          loop loop_1
          int 20h
```

the bx register had hex values that didnt correspond to what i thought they should have.

I am lost; I'm trying to traverse a bit pattern and I don't know whether I'm actually traversing a bit pattern or what. They have chucked is in the deep end and have no help with regards to understanding. I don't want the code guys, I just wanna understand what happens happens to the hex and how the pc sees it, and how it is stored in the register. Oh and if I can step through a bit pattern using the pointer register si to get the actual bit each time.

Sorry if this sounds stupid, I've tried reading up and there is too much out there and nothing specific to what I'm looking for. I'm new at assembly, first program ever lol. I have thought of the pseudo code in c++ but converting to assembly is another story for another day!

Comment: `db` defines bytes. `num1: db 06h,06h,06h` defines a label `num1` on a location that has 3 consecutive bytes which have value `06h` (or in binary, that's `00000110`. If you want to look at the 3 bytes at location `num1` as a single number, then it would be, `060606h` or binary `000001100000011000000110`.

Comment: @lurker thank you for clearing that up, that now makes sense to me! So I need them to be separate as stated initially. So 00000110. How would I put the first byte into a register and then start traversing the byte in its binary form ie (00000110). I need to step through it and for each 0 print something or each 1 print something. Can't grasp how I'd access it

Comment: If you need to "taverse the bits", look up the x86 bit instructions. Shift, rotate, test, etc. The x86 instruction manual is your friend here and you should browse it for goodies. Lots of information online if you search for it. Stackoverflow.com isn't really a tutorial site. So it's best to look this stuff up, try some things, and then ask a specific question when you get stuck on a particular implementation item.

Comment: @lurker okay I will do that thank you!

Comment: Hint: you could for example and the byte with 1 and then shift right, repeating until the byte is 0

Comment: if this is a 32-bit program, why are you only allowed to use 16-bit registers? ax, etc are the 16-bit versions. eax, ebx, etc are the 32-bit versions.

Comment: It is a 32bit program, however that's what the course specifies. They want us to use 16 bit registers only. I have it the program and will be posting solution soon. Thank you all for your help.